# Running easy rsa in a bat file on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, certificate, openvpn

I want to create certificates with easy rsa.

Currently I change a few parameters in the "easy-rsa" file and run following commands:

1. EasyRSA-Start.bat to start the easy-rsa shell
2. within the shell I run `./easyrsa init-pki`
3. `./easyrsa build-ca nopass`
4. `./easyrsa build-server-full server nopass`
5. `./easyrsa build-client-full <Client> nopass`
6. `/easyrsa gen-dh`
7. `exit` to exit the shell
8. `openvpn --genkey tls-auth ta.key`

All those steps generates me the certificates and keys I want but I want to automate it so I only have a single place to change a few parameters like the name or expire date and run it with a double click to generate everything at once.

For the default values, I can just copy out the var setup section of the script and change a few defaults there. But on the next step I need to run a new shell and I don't know how to write commands in the bat file that will be run in the new shell.

Is there any way to automate this?

---

Edit: I think I got a step closer. I saw that the .bat file from easyrsa just calls an .sh file where things happens so I did modify the .sh file to include the default values I want to have at the top and also set the mode to batch so the generation of the certificates will only take the default values and no human input.

At the very bottom there is the line `bin/sh` that opens the shell. I modified it to `bin/sh "./easyrsa help"` and when running the .bat file now I saw that the help text is printed to the shell so thats how I can provide the shell with commands.

The problem is, the writing `bin/sh "./easyrsa build-ca nopass"`, the shell will print that running that command has succed without errors but first the code execution was way to fast and also there where no generated certificates...

Any idea how to improve this?

Comment: How are you running batch (.bat) and bash (.sh) on the same system?

Comment: batch-files run in `cmd` and bash runs in a bash/sh shell. To determine your problems, you would need to simply log your shell/bash script results to a log file to see where the errors are. but I suspect that you're shells script path is not the same as the files you're running, so do not use relative paths, instead point full path to the commands. Add a shebang to the top of the script `#!/bin/sh` then give it executable rights `chmod +x scriptname.sh` specify full path to the commands, i.e `/opt/somedir/easyrsa build-ca nopass` then run the script as `./script.sh`

Comment: @Gerhard The problem is, there are no errors. The shell prints out that there where no errors running the command. When running "./easyrsa help" I also see the help prompt so the path to easyrsa is right.

Comment: @SomethingDark easy-rsa provides some kind of sh shell. The batch file to start easy-rsa will just start this shell where you can use all commands

Comment: rights should also be okey because when just running `bbin/sh` to open the shell and running `./easyrsa build-ca nopass` manual it will generate an certificate